# How to execute a LINQ statement without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, datatable

I have the following function

```
Public Function GetPositionBySchoolID(ByVal SchoolID As Integer) As CPAPositionsDataTable
    Dim positions As New CPAPositionsDataTable
    Dim tmp = (From pos In PositionsAdapter.GetData()
                Where (pos.SchoolID = SchoolID)
                Select pos)
    tmp.ToList.ForEach(Sub(i) positions.ImportRow(i))
    Return positions
End Function
```

And I was wondering if there is any way to cut out assigning the LINQ result to tmp and just work with the result directly, i.e.

```
Public Function GetPositionBySchoolID(ByVal SchoolID As Integer) As CPAPositionsDataTable
    Dim positions As New CPAPositionsDataTable
    (From pos In PositionsAdapter.GetData()
                Where (pos.SchoolID = SchoolID)
                Select pos).ToList.ForEach(Sub(i) positions.ImportRow(i))
    Return positions
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you can't use the query syntax:

```
PositionsAdapter.GetData().Where(Function(pos) pos.SchoolID = SchoolID) _
                          .ToList().ForEach(Sub(i) positions.ImportRow(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply iterate over it in a foreach loop. The return value of the LINQ operators are `IEnumerable<T>` deep down, so iterateable.

Also, you could create a `ForEach` method (this wasn't included as the LINQ stack is about **not** having side effects, and `ForEach` is all about side effects) as an extension on `IEnumerable<T>`, you don't have to call `ToList` before.

Comment: Ahh, true, seems I got lambda stuck in my head and was over-complicating it. I could have simply done...
'        For Each item In (From pos In PositionsAdapter.GetData()
                    Where (pos.SchoolID = SchoolID)
                    Select pos)
            positions.ImportRow(item)
        Next